# Will BUG_ON print message

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel

I have hit `BUG_ON` in kernel code. I want to know what went wrong at that time.
`BUG_ON` will check for the condition and if it is true, it will panic.

Will `BUG_ON` print the messages in /var/log/messages?
Will it print the value it is checking before panicking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. From [include/asm-generic/bug.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-generic/bug.h#L48):

```
#ifndef HAVE_ARCH_BUG
#define BUG() do { \
    printk("BUG: failure at %s:%d/%s()!\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__); \
    panic("BUG!"); \
} while (0)
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_ARCH_BUG_ON
#define BUG_ON(condition) do { if (unlikely(condition)) BUG(); } while(0)
#endif
```

Provided your kernel is compiled appropriately, `BUG_ON` will print a message before panicking.

Comment: Note that the message will probably **not** be logged in `/var/log/messages`, as that would require that the system continue running long enough for your logger to write it to disk. A panic kills the system pretty much immediately.

Answer (score 1):

the messages will not be logged to /var/log/messages most of the time. You will be able to see if you have configured serial console in the machine. if you want more details you might have to add printk and recompile kernel

http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelHacking-HOWTO/Debugging_Kernel

or you can collect a vmcore to get more details on the panic

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/crash.html

this works for suse or rhel. for other os they might have similar mechanisms